# Invisible overlay bottom right corner in windows 11

Tags: windows-11

I have upgraded my laptop from windows 10 to windows 11.

Since the upgrade, I noticed that I cannot click anything in a rectangular area at the bottom right of the screen. This of course prevents me from clicking/selecting anything in that area.

What is that, and how can I make it disappear?

Comment: This is a nice self-answers Q+A, but it's not directly about programming, so I think it would be better on [su].

Answer (score 1):

according to here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/661550/ghost-window-in-windows-11.html:

This shadow is a known issue with certain windows 11 devices. This will resolve the issue:

- Press the `Win + R` keys together on your keyboard to open the Run command window.
- In the Run command search field, type `sysdm.cpl` and hit Enter to open the System Properties window.
- In the System Properties dialogue box, select `the Advanced tab`.
- Click `Settings...` in `Performance section`.
- Under the Visual Effects tab, **uncheck** `Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop and uncheck the option`.
- Click apply.